# Beginning with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm getting pretty good with javascript, but I want to edit files, so I need to use PHP. I don't need to do any extreme, just insert some text and change some hex values.

A good model of what I want would probably be an online text editor in PHP, but I can't seem to find any, nor any tutorials on it.

Are there any resources that would help?

Comment: You don't need to use PHP. There are other (IMO better) technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this now, I would have to say that The New Boston's tutorials are great for getting started in a language.

http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11

Answer (score 3):

Check these out http://www.webgeekly.com/lessons/4-web-based-code-editors-that-let-you-code-online/ =)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of it at first, but will these let me test PHP script? I didn't realize that I wouldn't be able to test it like I would HTML or javascript.

Comment: @user828584 You can paste some simple php codes into http://codepad.org and tick the Run Code box to test them. If you want to do anything complicated though like manage your own PHP settings or use a database you should set up your own localhost server. If you're on Windows you can install WAMP, on Linux or Mac OS X it's easy to set up an Apache web server.

Comment: @user828584: youll need to have a server with PHP running on it. Usually one would set up a local environemnt with a webserver and php and often a database. You can finsd all=in-one solutions for this like XAMP, WAMP, and Zend Server CE.

Comment: @user828584 yea among those web-based code editors, Kodingen has some pretty advanced features for you to test your code (including PHP)

Answer (score 2):

Read [Head First PHP & MySQL](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/) book.

Answer (score 0):

To get php running locally, the easiest thing to learn on is going to be either:

- WAMP for Windows : http://www.wampserver.com/en/
- MAMP for Mac : http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Some places to get started learning:

- Tizag's tutorial - http://www.tizag.com/phpT/
- Some php tutorial videos:  http://phpvideotutorials.com/free
- http://php.net - this will likely be a bit overwhelming for just getting started

And for the older schoolers, there are lots and lots of dead trees on the subject - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book

Answer (score 0):

As i said in my comment to Legolas, I dont remember where I started when i know 0 PHP or serverside scripting.

That said i would suggest coming up with a feature you want to develop - like your text editor. Then google for tutorials of implementations in PHP. Youre bound to find a ton for most things. Then read the tutorial learn what the code is actually doing. Look up each function call in the php documentation so that you understand it. Anything you dont understand or have trouble with you will at this point have enough specifics to post here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

tutorials by php.net itself! One of the most reliable sources for learning php.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>http://www.w3schools.com/ would be a good start.</strike>

**Edit:**

Please visit www.w3fools.com and ignore my answer !

Comment: [No, it wouldnt.](http://www.w3fools.com). Im not exactly sure where to start if you know nothing, i dont remeber where i started but the [online php documentation](http://php.net) is invaluable - especially the comments.

Comment: w3schools has to be one of the worst places to start.

Comment: @racekemup420: ha ha. lul What ? It helped me with the basics. It's just a suggestion/opinion. Go ahead and down vote me because `i have an opinion` ? :P lol

Comment: @Legolas it is pretty bad. Let me refer you to http://w3fools.com/, looks like prod already did.

Comment: w3schools is full of errors, a bad okace to start

Comment: Agree with @prodigitalson though !!

Comment: @Matt : Oh my god ! Wow. Seriously :O I had my intervention I guess.

Comment: @all the commenters above: apologies ! Lol. Never knew w3fools.com existed. I might as well spread the word then :P